# Atom Editor - Snippets Configuration access

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

Can an Atom snippet access the atom configuration?

I need to create a snippet which needs access to the *preferred line length* setting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this page is useful for you:

http://blog.atom.io/2014/10/31/language-scoped-config.html

This page has a link to:

https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.0/Config#instance-set